# Converting vector<unsigned char> which contains /0 in it to char* without losing data?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a server client program in which I try to send binary data from my C++ server to my C# client. when I'm trying to convert the data from my `vector<unsigned char>` to a `char*` I notice that only half of the data is sent, and I'm afraid that it might be because my data contains `\0` in it.

I convert like this:

```
const char* response = reinterpret_cast<char*>(requestResult.response.data());
```

and my data looks like this:

```
    [0]: 204 'Ì'
    [1]: 0 '\0'
    [2]: 0 '\0'
    [3]: 0 '\0'
    [4]: 12 '\f'
    [5]: 123 '{'
    [6]: 34 '\"'
    [7]: 115 's'
    [8]: 116 't'
    [9]: 97 'a'
    [10]: 116 't'
    [11]: 117 'u'
    [12]: 115 's'
    [13]: 34 '\"'
    [14]: 58 ':'
    [15]: 49 '1'
    [16]: 125 '}'
```

When I check the result after the conversion I only see the first byte in the data ( 204 - 'Ì' ) and it is a bit problematic :]

the sending itself is done using this function using socket.cpp:

```
{
    if (send(sc, (char*)message, strlen((char*)message), 0) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        throw std::exception("Error while sending message to client");
    }
}
```

How can I convert a data like this to a char* so I could send all of the data correctly?

Comment: If you're using a function that processes C strings, it will stop at the null byte. You should use a function for sending arrays, not strings; it should take the length as a parameter. Get the size of `requestResult.response` and use that as the length to send.

Answer (score 2):

Your propblem is with

```
strlen((char*)message)
```

`strlen` is going to stop at the first null character in the "c-string" and so that is why you are only getting the data until the first null character.  Fortunetly you can get around this by passing the size of the vector instead of using `strlen`.  That will look like

```
send(sc, (char*)message, name_of_vector.size(), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I check the result after the conversion I only see the first byte in the data ( 204 - 'Ì' )

Check how, string printing? That thing isn't a string, it's a data buffer of size `requestResult.response.size()`. If you print it accordingly you'll see there's no data loss.

Which is doubly true since there's no data processing done in the code you've shown, `data()` returns a pointer to the internal data buffer and does no further changes.

It's not entirely obvious to me why you'd have random garbage in the first four bytes of what looks like JSON, but the simplest way to get to it would simply be to use `requestResult.response.data() + 4`. Also there's no need to reinterpret anything, the items in your array are already `char`.

Edit since you added the send function: As I said above, simply use the correct size:

```
send(sc, requestResult.response.data(), requestResult.response.size(), 0)
```

Comment: cast is needed for `unsigned` conversion.

Comment: I'm sending binary data and then some Json, some weird requirements of the project. appreciating your answer, thanks :D

Comment: @Jarod42 I don't believe you. In fact I posit that `send` (the POSIX socket function) takes a `const void *`, which will accept signed or unsigned chars, so no cast at all is needed.

Comment: But indeed unsigned conversion might be unneeded. My point was about *"the items in your array are already `char`"* which is pedantically false, `unsigned char` != `char` (!= `signed char`).